# AngularJS: select not binding to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple form that I wish to POST to my server.  The bindings in AngularJS work except on my select.  On my select I'm not getting a value:

Here is my markup:

```
...
<div id="divAccountName" class="isNotAvailable">
    <label for="inputAccountName">Account Name:</label>
    <input name="inputAccountName" required type="text" data-ng-model="register.accountName" data-ng-blur="checkAccountAvailability($event)" />
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="account">
    <label for="inputAccountType">Account Type:</label>
    <select name="inputAccountType" data-ng-model="register.accountType" data-ng-options="a.Type for a in accountTypes.value" required>
        <option value="" data-ng-if="false"></option>
    </select>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="recaptcha">
    <div id="contact-recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" data-ng-click="registerUser(register)" />
</div>
```

The register object that gets passed to registerUser() has all my input values except the select value.  So when I $resource.save() it to my webserver the value for register.accountType is null.

The account types are populating correctly from my controller, so they are selectable.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Yes, here it is:  http://jsfiddle.net/stevereece/kfhsv3mf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Hope this plunker will help you

```
<select name="inputAccountType" data-ng-model="register.accountType" data-ng-options="a.name for a in accType track by a.type" required="">
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lsO6FhKcqimm9lw6MFR?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not sure why your's works and mine does not.  I thought initializing the object to null would fix it, but it does not.

Comment: hi i have updated your fiddler problem is you have to initialized select object. http://jsfiddle.net/kfhsv3mf/8/